# Getting started with a WordPress plugin integration

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to add Docusign to a custom WordPress plugin. We need to conditionally send out a remote signing request when a member signs up to the site. I've gone through the Quickstart project and the examples, but I'm not sure how to take those examples and then integrate them with our plugin. Would the entire Quickstart project get added to a subfolder and then referenced somehow? How can I tell which files are necessary to the functionality I want, and what can be removed? I tried loading the docusign composer package to the plugin along with the Quickstart's `ds_config.php` file and `EG002SigningViaEmail.php`, and got the error `Class "Example\Controllers\eSignBaseController" not found`, so clearly I'm missing some things. Sorry if the answer is really obvious, I don't work with APIs often.

Comment: which quickstart did you choose? Auth Code Grant? JWT? or the right-most full package?

Comment: I chose the right full package since I wasn't sure which would work best (though I believe it's JWT for my use case) @InbarGazit

Comment: so then you did composer install and then you did php -S localhost:8080 ?

Comment: Yeah, I did both of those and tested the "Send an envelope with a remote (email) signer and cc recipient" example. It worked, but this is still in a separate folder from the WordPress plugin I'm developing, and I'm not sure how to tweak the example files and bring them into my plugin properly. @InbarGazit

Comment: You'll need:
SigningViaEmailService.php but you'll also have to worry about authentication. You don't need the controllers

Comment: For auth you either need CodeGrantService.php if you use ACG or you need JWTService.php if you're using JWT

Comment: The rest is between your CodePress app and making sure PHP code gets all the needed information to make API calls to DocuSign

Comment: Thank you, this helped me get started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given in the comments so putting it here now:

To get the PHP code out of the quickstart into another project you need:

1. `SigningViaEmailService.php` - code for sending envelopes
2. Either `CodeGrantService.php` if you use ACG or you need `JWTService.php` if you're using JWT

And composer needs to find the DocuSign PHP SDK as well.